# Does order matter when subtracting unsigned integers in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

While using unsigned integers(`size_t`), MSVC complains as below:
<sub>(It looks like gcc and clang compiles these.)</sub>

```
size_t a = 1, b = 2;    
-a;   // C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned.
-a+b; // Also the same error as above.
b-a;  // Compiles well.
```

The error messages for `-a` or `-a+b` are understandable since `size_t` is an unsigned type.

But why and how is `b-a` compiled?

Is this a correct way to subtract two unsigned type integers?

Comment: do you understand that the result of `-a` is always a negative number while `a-b` can be positive, when `a` and `b` are positive?

Comment: Unlike in maths, `b-a` is not equivalent to `b + (-a)`.

Comment: please do not add `Question resolved!` into your question. The way to mark a question as resolved is to accept an answer. You could write an answer yourself if you like. If you don't like, and don't think this question needs further input, you could delete it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai If you answer in the comments you can hardly complain about the OP not clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @Sneftel there was no complaint just trying to inform. Though, no matter if or where the answer was given, adding it inside the question makes the question pointless

Comment: The first two code examples are valid and their meanings are well defined. If the compiler refuses to compile them it's because you have some non-standard setting, typically "pretend that anything the compiler writer thinks might be misunderstood is an error" (more typically called "treat warnings as errors").

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right, thank you. I checked the setting ("Treat specific warnings as errors") in Visual Studio, but no warnings were listed(it was empty), but the `/sdl` compiler option was the reason why this warning became an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that, in C++, there are *two different minus operators - unary and binary.*
So, unlike in maths, `b-a` is not equivalent to `b + (-a)`, as @molbdnilo commented.
It seems that gcc and clang compile the code in the question though.

I just simply thought like doing math, which is a big mistake. Thanks for all the comments.

**Edit**: As @PeteBecker commented, the codes in the question are all valid, but the error is related to the compiler setting.

I found some settings related to "treat warnings as errors" in Visual Studio. In project property settings page:

1) C/C++ -> General -> "Treat warnings as errors": Yes(`/WX`) or No(`/WX-`)
  2) C/C++ -> General -> "SDL checks": Yes(`/sdl`) or No(`/sdl-`)
  3) C/C++ -> Advanced -> "Treat specific warnings as errors"

In my case, 1) was "No" and 3) was empty, but 2) was "Yes", and that was the reason for the error. The `/sdl` (Enable Additional Security Checks) compiler option elevated the warning to the error. See MSDN ["Compiler warning (level 2) C4146"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-2-c4146?view=msvc-170) for details.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it to change its status to Answered. Just a reminder :)